# It is possible to read AWS Environment Properties from Java or PHP?

Tags: java, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The question is simple: I have some Environment Properties (also called Environment Variables by many) in my AWS instace. As far I know, I can access those properties in my .config file inside the .ebextensions folder, but there is any way to access those properties from Java or PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use standard methods for accessing values of environment variables defined in Elastic Beanstalk.

So for Java you could use `System.getenv("MY_VAR")` and `getenv` for php.

Answer (score 1):

In elastic beanstalk Java container the environment variables are set as system properties, so you have to do this for Java: `System.getProperty("myPropName")`